# Conditional statements and RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm struggling with using RSpec with conditional statements. What is an example of a spec file for the following lines of code? The drive method is what I am trying to break down into a spec file. I'm not sure how to go about the conditional statements.

```
class Car

def initialize
  @fuel = 10
  @distance = 0 
end

def drive(miles)
  if (@fuel -= miles/20) >= 0
    @distance += miles
    @fuel -= miles/20
else 
    @distance += @fuel * 20 
    @fuel = 0 
    puts "You're out of gas!"
end
end

def fuel_up
  gallons_needed = 10 - @fuel
  puts "The amount of gallons needed will cost you $#{3.5 * gallons_needed}"
end

def to_s
  puts "I'm a car. I've driven #{@distance} miles and have #{@fuel} gallons of gas left."
end

end

car_a = Car.new
car_b = Car.new
car_a.drive(10)
car_a.to_s
car_b.drive(133)
car_b.to_s
car_b.fuel_up
car_a.fuel_up
car_a.drive(500)
```

Comment: `10/20` is `0`. Are you aware of that?

Comment: sawa - yes I'm aware of that! It was in our instructions to do it that way, although I'm not sure if that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need info on how `@distance` and `@fuel` are calculated and/or initialized.

As an example, based on what I can tell about your code:

```
require 'rspec'

describe Car do
  it '#drive' do
    car = Car.new
    car.drive(10)

    expect(car.distance).to eq 10
    expect(car.fuel).to eq 0.5
  end

end
```

From a testing standpoint, you give your function a number and your function does some stuff to some other variables.  That's what you should test for, specifically what the expectation of those calculations are.

Comment: @sawa yep you're right, but maybe my test will bring that to light for him/her.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I added the rest of the code so you can get a better picture. I understand your spec above, but do I need to write out any of the @fuel -= distance, etc in the spec, or just what the method should be expecting to do .. i.e. expect(car.distance).to eq 10?

Comment: You're not testing that the `-=` operator is doing it's job, you're testing that your function given X, does Y & Z.  You could rewrite my test for all the permutations and expect the results necessary.